# What is the meaning of Possible null pointer dereference in findbug?

Tags: java, find, sonarqube, findbugs

I am using Sonar and I have got this kind of violation from it for a peace of my code:

```
 Correctness - Possible null pointer dereference
```

Has anyone know about this rule in findbugs? I searched a lot but I can not find a good sample code (in Java) which describe this rule, unfortunately findbugs site did not have any sample code or good description about this rule.

Why does this violation appear?

Comment: Post some code where the recommendation is showing up!

Comment: I want to see sample code about this findbugs rule. I want to generally know it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It says [here](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH)

```
NP: Possible null pointer dereference (NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH)
```

> *There is a branch of statement that, if executed, guarantees that a null value will be dereferenced, which would generate a NullPointerException when the code is executed. Of course, the problem might be that the branch or statement is infeasible and that the null pointer exception can't ever be executed; deciding that is beyond the ability of FindBugs.*

If you would have posted some code it would be easier to answer.

**EDIT** I don't see a lot of documentation but here is one [example](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/EXP01-J.+Do+not+use+a+null+in+a+case+where+an+object+is+required)! Hope this helps!

Comment: My code is very complicated and also i changed my code and it fixed but i did not understand this findbugs rule.

Comment: Well than as it says `There is a branch of statement that, if executed, guarantees that a null value will be dereferenced, which would generate a NullPointerException when the code is executed.` means you potentially are assigning a `null` to a variable and using it again which might cause an exception.

Comment: Please give me a sample code. I read this description before !

Answer (score 20):

a sample code is something like this.

```
String s = null ;
if (today is monday){
    s = "Monday" ;
else if (today is tuesday){
    s = "Tuesday" ;
}
System.out.println(s.length()); //Will throw a null pointer if today is not monday or tuesday.
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay

This is two simple Examples :
First one gives a : Possible null pointer dereference

```
1. Error
     ArrayList a = null;
     a.add(j, PointSet.get(j));
     // now i'm trying to add to the ArrayList 
     // because i'm giving it null it gives me the "Possible null pointer dereference"

2. No Error
     ArrayList a = new ArrayList<>();
     a.add(j, PointSet.get(j));
     // adding elements to the ArrayList
     // no problem
```

Simple ?

Answer (score 1):

In simple language, if a variable value is assigned as null, and you try to access it with any inbuilt method like add/get. Then null pointer dereference issue comes with SONAR. Because there are changes for it go null, and throw null pointer exception. Try to avoid it if possible.

For example:

```
File file=null;
file.getName();
```

will throw "Possible null pointer dereference"

It may not happen directly as mentioned in the example, it can be unintentionally.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue with the following piece of code:-

```
BufferedReader br = null;
    String queryTemplate = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(queryFile));
        queryTemplate = br.readLine();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      //  throw exception
    } catch (IOException e) {
       // throw exception
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
```

Here, the `br` BufferedReader can be `null` in `br.close()`. However it can only be `null` if `new BufferedReader()` fails, in which case we are throwing the relevant exceptions.

This is thus a false warning. `Findbugs` docs mention the same:-

```
   This may lead to a NullPointerException when the code is executed.  
   Note that because FindBugs currently does not prune infeasible 
   exception paths, this may be a false warning.
```

Comment: ... and since you're using a finally block, you're guaranteeing that, after the exception from the bufferedreader is caught and (probably) rethrown, a nullpointer occurs...